# PhoneGap File Upload to WCF

Tags: wcf, file-upload, cordova

How do I upload an image from the mobile device to my external database?

Here is my current WCF Service:

Interface:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Upload", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped), CorsEnabled]
string UploadProfileImage(string image);
```

Class Method:

```
public string UploadProfileImage(string image)    
{ 
    // Upload code needs to go here. 
}
```

I can post using ajax just fine, I'm just lost on how to do it with an image.

Here is the jQuery example of how I do a post.

```
// This is the success function that gets called after selecting an image from my device
function uploadSuccess(imageURI) {
    uploadImage(imageURI);
}

function uploadImage(imageURI)
{
    var data = '{"image":"' + imageURI + '"}'
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.101.55:8848/api/Upload",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload an image from a client to your REST service? If that is the case your parameter for the service method should be of type stream rather than string.

Comment: Yeah thanks.  I just figured that out.  My biggest problem is that I get an error in LogCat debug console that says 'Error Bad Request'.  If I could figure out what the error is I could probally get much further.

Comment: The bad request might be due to your client sending in byte array where as the service method was expecting a string. Just change the service method param type to stream and hopefully that should get it working. Make sure about setting readerQuotas for uploading large files

Comment: I'm getting the same error message. Bad Request.

Comment: Try to inspect your request using Fiddler on how the raw request looks like. The bad request might be due to the size of the file as well. Try using a very small file to get it working first and then you can add the readerQuotas for uploading large files. Enable tracing(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to get the exact reason on why you get a bad request error.

Comment: This is possibly my error. I do not see the error coming through on fiddler from my remote device, so I used an application on my machine to do a post for me.  Here is the error: The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Incoming message for operation 'UploadProfileImage' 
   (contract 'IValues' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. 
   The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.

Comment: You need to set the responsemessageformat in your service. If you are posting JSON from your client then set it accordingly in a similar fashion on how you have set your responseformat on the service method

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot achieve this using jquery due to cross domain posting limition.
 You have to create form and point the form "action" to the url of the service method, add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag.
Don't forget to change the service input paramater type to be "stream"